# What race is being discussed here?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-development

In the novel "[Heir to The Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_to_the_Empire)", we have the following scene:

> Halfway across the room, one of the sculptures had not disappeared
>   with the others. Sitting all alone in its globe of light, it slowly
>   writhed on its pedestal like a wave in some bizarre alien ocean.
>
> "Yes," Thrawn said from behind him. "That one is indeed real."
>
> "It's . . . very interesting," Pellaeon managed. The sculpture was
>   strangely hypnotic.
>
> "Isn't it?" Thrawn agreed, his voice sounding almost wistful. "It was
>   my one failure, out on the Fringes. The one time when understanding a
>   race's art gave me no insight at all into its psyche. At least not at
>   the time. Now, I believe I'm finally beginning to understand them."
>
> "I'm sure that will prove useful in the future," Pellaeon offered
>   diplomatically.
>
> **"I doubt it," Thrawn said, in that same wistful voice. "I wound up
>   destroying their world."**

In the years since, we have learned much about Thrawn, his origins, and the Chiss people in general. However, I'm not aware of any information regarding Thrawn destroying a planet.

**Do we know anything further about the alien race being discussed here?**

Comment: Maybe we’ll find out when *Thrawn* is released. ;)

Answer (score 4):

This event seems to have been discussed in the book's accompanying [RPG Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Force_Rising_Sourcebook). In short, **the race probably had a name, but it's irrelevant since they're all dead now.**

> *The Victory-class Star Destroyer Iron Fist orbited high above **the
> planet designated UR41-284. Like so many of the worlds in the Unknown
> Regions, the small red planet had no official name in the Imperial
> charts. If the inhabitants of the world had a name for their planet,
> it was not recorded on Captain Ferob's datapad.** In fact, little more
> than the raw planet specifications appeared on the Captain's glowing
> datapad screen. He knew its orbital path, its gravity, its atmosphere
> content. He knew where the primitive centers of civilization were,
> what kind of technology level the inhabitants possessed. But he knew
> nothing of a personal nature. To him, the planet was just another
> sphere to be charted as his ship continued its five year mission
> through the Unknown Regions.*
>
> *The comm unit beeped once, calling for Captain Ferob's attention. It
> was the command frequency, which meant that Grand Admiral Thrawn was
> calling from the planet's surface. Ferob reached for the toggle switch
> without hesitation. To delay, to keep the Grand Admiral waiting, would
> be to risk the Grand Admiral's wrath. After serving under Thrawn for
> almost three years, he knew how terrible that wrath could be.*
>
> *"Ferob here, sir" the Captain said into the comm unit, trying to keep
> his voice steady. He respected Thrawn, he even feared him, but he
> still had trouble keeping his revulsion to himself. How could the
> Emperor make this ... this alien ... a Grand Admiral?*
>
> *"The inhabitants of this world refuse to submit to the Emperor's will,
> Captain Ferob," Thrawn informed him, his voice full of the calm
> ruthlessness the Captain had come to know so well since heading into
> the Unknown Regions with Thrawn. "I am providing you with the
> coordinates of a portion of the major village cluster. Begin
> bombardments on my mark. I want you to level everything within a
> seventy-kilometer radius of those coordinates without touching the
> coordinates themselves. I want that portion of land to remain intact."*
>
> *"Understood, Grand Admiral," Ferob responded, entering the orders into
> his datapad. He ejected the data card and handed it to his first
> officer, who would pass along the orders to the gunners and make sure
> they were carried out to the letter.*
>
> *"A question, Captain Ferob?" the Grand Admiral asked through the still
> open comm channel. Perceptive as always, Ferob thought. "If I may
> sir," he started tentatively. "What's so important about those
> coordinates?"*
>
> *"Art, Captain," Thrawn said, a touch of excitement creeping through
> his command voice. "The coordinates bound the village cluster's museum
> district."*
>
> *"Of course, sir," Ferob said, remembering the Grand Admiral's peculiar
> obsession. "Should I prepare your pick-up team?"*
>
> *"In good time," Thrawn responded. "For now let's teach this world what
> it means to deny the Empire. You may begin the bombardment, Captain
> Ferob."*
>
> *"And then the art, sir?"*
>
> *"And then the art."*
>
> *The bombardment began ...*
>
> <sub><sup>[Dark Force Rising Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Force_Rising_Sourcebook)</sup></sub>

[image]